# How to pass values as integers from Python into a VBA macro without errors?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I've been working on automating some of the reporting tasks at my job, and have been using Selenium with Python for webdriving and then getting the data into Excel and then triggering a VBA Macro within that spreadsheet to organize the data the way I need it to.

I know that VBA can use Selenium, and I know Python can edit Excel worksheets, but I find they're suited best to the tasks I'm giving them.

I've had little trouble integrating them by getting Python just to trigger a Macro, and then it's work is done. However, this time I'm trying to pass certain variables into the macro.

I'll use brackets to represent sensitive info even though that's probably bad because brackets are used in code of course, but don't worry there's no brackets in my code.

Here's the code that triggers the macro:

```
if os.path.exists(r"PATH.xlsm"):
    thisxl = wincl.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wby = thisxl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(r"PATH.xlsm"))
    thisxl.Application.Run("MODULE", [STRING_VARIABLE], [STRING VARIABLE], [INTEGER VARIABLE], [INTEGER VARIABLE])
    wby.Close(SaveChanges=1)
    thisxl.Quit()
    del thisxl
```

Now, if I just run this code, it triggers the macro just fine. The only problem is, one of those variables is a code that helps to match certain constituent elements of the data to info retrieved from the web. In other words, imagine there are several names representing people in my dataset, and some of them are the same--the code makes sure that the macro recognized the unique individuals.

But when I try to match the codes, nothing matches. And so I tried making sure that Excel and Python both know that these codes are integers.

When I pass the variables from python to VBA, I have tried `int([CODE])` and then added a `[CODE] As Integer` to the part of the VBA function where one passes in the variables.

This causes error:

```
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 14, in Run
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352566), None)
```

It clearly seems to be some kind of TypeError, but I'm not sure why if I've made sure to match the types. Do Python and VBA have different definitions of integer? Perhaps I'm just matching the types incorrectly.

Additionally, as a test, I MsgBoxed the passed code (before I tried to pass it as an integer) and the code as it is in the excel doc, and this was the display:

[image]

So clearly, the numbers actually do match, it's just some type or formatting issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try passing as variant in VBA

Comment: A Python `integer` is not the same as a VBA `Integer` - that's a 16 bit signed data type (`short`). `Long` is the 32 bit signed type (`int`), and `LongLong` is 64 bits.

Comment: If [CODE] is 54151354 you need to use `Long` in VBA; the range of `Integer` is [-32768, 32767]

Comment: @xidgel The numbers are not matching, but that did indeed allow me to pass them in. Thank you! That is a good thing to know about Excel in general.

Answer (score 1):

@xidgel Answered correctly. I needed to use data type Long for VBA not Integer.